# I need to run a GET request every minute continuously and insert it into a database. Even if the application isnt running, how do I implement this?

Tags: database, h2

I need to do a GET request every minute, which will give me a JSON file with several values. I need to insert this into my database when I receive it.

I already know how to process the received file but I don't know how to continuously run the GET request even with my application closed.

I know this must be done through the backend but I can't figure out how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.